# Concat 2 array of objects conditionally in mongoose

Tags: arrays, mongodb, object, concatenation, aggregate

I have 2 mongoose objects, 1 is operation that has an array of tasks

```
     "operation": [
            {
                "_id": "6493f6d6dc70ad504984301d",
                "name": "za",
                "imageUrl": "https://Standup.png",
                "reward": 232,
                "description": "hihihihi",
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "name": "create account",
                        "description": "create it"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "create login acccount login",
                        "description": "login and get point here to get points"
                    }
                ],
                "expirationDate": "2023-06-27T19:00:00.000Z",
               
               
        "pages": 1,
        "count": 1
    }
    }
```

and second i have tasks proofs which has array of tasks proofs with url,

```
     "operationId": "6493f6d6dc70ad504984301d",
        "userId": "647f076a4b469646fb0c6294",
        "taskProofs": [
            {
                "name": "create account",
                "url": "Task.com",
                "_id": "649922c126c23693b0178c75"
            }
        ],`your text`
```

now i want to aggregate the two like if a task has a task proof, it should return something like

```
"tasks": [
                    {
                        "name": "create account",
                        "description": "create it",
                        "url": "Task.com",
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "create login acccount login",
                        "description": "login and get point here to get points"
              
                    }
                ],
```

i tried this

```
 Operation.aggregate([
        { $match: filter },
        { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
        { $skip: skip },
        { $limit: +limit },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "operation_work_proofs",
            let: { operationId: "$_id" },
            pipeline: [
              {
                $match: {
                  userId: ObjectId(userId),
                  $expr: { $eq: ["$operationId", "$$operationId"] },
                },
              },
              {
                $project: {
                  _id: 0,
                  "taskProofs.name": 1,
                  "taskProofs._id": 1,
                  "taskProofs.isApproved": 1,
                },
              },
            ],

            as: "taskProofs",
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: {
            path: "$taskProofs",
            preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
          },
        },
        // concatinate tasks with task arrays
        {
          $addFields: {
            totaltasks: {
              $concatArrays: [
                { $ifNull: ["$taskProofs.taskProofs", []] },
                "$tasks",
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        // filter tasks duplicates
        {
          $addFields: {
            tasksList: {
              $reduce: {
                input: "$totaltasks",
                initialValue: [],
                in: {
                  $concatArrays: [
                    "$$value",
                    {
                      $cond: [
                        {
                          $in: ["$$this.name", "$$value.name"],
                        },
                        [],
                        ["$$this"],
                      ],
                    },
                  ],
                },
              },
            },
          },
        },

        {
          $project: {
            _id: 1,
            name: 1,
            imageUrl: 1,
            reward: 1,
            description: 1,
            expirationDate: 1,
            tasksList: 1,
            taskProofs: 1,
            tasks: 1,
          },
        },
      ]),
```

but it either returns task or task proof, not the combined object, so how can i achieve this